# Emails not arriving on dovecot/postfix (debian)

Tags: dovecot

I've setup the lasts postfix/dovecot on Debian. I can login and check mails from thunderbird in ssl. But when I send a mail to the test user (test@blue-lands.com), the mails nevers arrives and no error message sent back...

Here is the logs:

Dovecot.log:

```
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before/accept initialization [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before/accept initialization [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: unknown state [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 read client hello A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write server hello A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write certificate A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write key exchange A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write server done A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 flush data [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3 read client certificate A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3 read client certificate A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 read client key exchange A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 read finished A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write session ticket A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write change cipher spec A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 write finished A [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3 flush data [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x20, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully [83.194.107.152]
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Warning: SSL alert: where=0x4008, ret=256: warning close notify [83.194.107.152]
```

dovecot-info.log:

```
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3-login: Info: Login: user=<test.blue-lands>, method=PLAIN, rip=83.194.107.152, lip=5.39.72.228, mpid=25104, TLS, session=<oaPp0Pjl0ABTwmu2>
2013-09-09 21:58:46 pop3(test.blue-lands): Info: Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/0, size=0
```

Postfix conf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
# Dovecot LDA
dovecot    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d $recipient
```

Dovecot.vonf:

```
## Fichier Configuration - Serveur POP (SSL) / IMAP (SSL) Dovecot
base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/

protocols = imap pop3 imaps pop3s

    protocol imap {
        listen = 5.39.72.228:143
        ssl_listen = 5.39.72.228:993
        login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
        mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
        mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
        imap_logout_format = bytes ( in=%i : out=%o )
    }

    protocol pop3 {
        listen = *:110
        ssl_listen = *:995
        pop3_enable_last = no
        login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
        mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
        mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
        pop3_logout_format = top=%t/%p, retr=%r/%b, del=%d/%m, size=%s
    }

    protocol managesieve {
        listen = *:2000
        login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve-login
        mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve
    #   managesieve_max_line_length = 65536
    #   managesieve_logout_format = bytes ( in=%i : out=%o )
    }

    plugin {
        sieve=~/.dovecot.sieve
        sieve_dir=~/.Sieve
    }

disable_plaintext_auth = no
shutdown_clients = yes

    auth default {
        mechanisms = plain login

        passdb pam {
             args = failure_show_msg=yes
        }

        userdb passwd {
            args =
        }

        socket listen {
            master {
                path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
                mode = 0666
            }

            client {
                path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
                mode = 0666
                user = postfix
                group = postfix
            }
        }
    }

##
## Logging
##
log_path = /var/log/dovecot/dovecot.log
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot/dovecot-info.log
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
syslog_facility = mail


##
## SSL settings
##

ssl = yes
ssl_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/ssl_keys/imap.crt
ssl_key_file = /etc/dovecot/ssl_keys/imap.key
ssl_ca_file = /etc/dovecot/ssl_keys/ca.crt
ssl_verify_client_cert = no
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2
verbose_ssl = yes

mail_location = maildir:~/.Maildir
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the output of ***/var/log/mail.log*** ?

Because as far as i think the mail.log would contain something like ***"could not connect to /var/run/dovecot/auth-master: permission denied"***.

If this is the case then all you have to do is change the permissions of ***/var/run/dovecot/auth-master*** so that ***vmail*** user can access it.

But there's a catch to it. Whenever dovecot is restarted the permissions are reverted. You will have to give them again or you can write a script that does that for you every time dovecot or system is restarted.

If this is not the case then post the log here for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

check errors in 
openssl s_client -connect mail.mydomain.com:995